# Module/class visible in whole project - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

So basically I need a class that will be visible in all sub directories of a project. The class is defined in the bar.py script and I need to instance an object in scripts where the `<here>` tag is placed.

The project structure look as follow and the program starts with the start_script.py.

```
base/
  start_script.py
  gui/
      __init__.py
      gui.py
      <here>
  vending/
      __init__.py
      vending.py
      <here>
  foo/
      __init__.py
      foo.py
      <here>
  bar/
      bar.py
      __init__.py
```

I already tried the relative import but it doesn't seems to work. Then I tried the dumbest solution to copy the required class everywhere I needed it, but I don't think it is a good practice to have copies of the same file all over the project.

The second solution that I tried is to copy the bar folder to the `site-packages`. It worked but I'm not sure if it is wise to copy a module that will be probably used only in this project to the `site-packages`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I edited my answer with the new content of the edited question)

Your project needs a `__init__.py` file at the same level as `start_script.py` to use relative imports.

Now you could add your class `SpecialSnowflake` in, for example, `start_script.py` and use it like this:

```
# file base/gui/gui.py
from ..start_script import SpecialSnowflake

# file base/vending/vending.py
from ..start_script import SpecialSnowflake

# file base/foo/foo.py
from ..start_script import SpecialSnowflake
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes it works, but thats not exactly what I'm looking for. I edited the question so maybe it is clearer now.

Comment: @ls2709 you need a `__init__.py` file inside `base/` directory as well for relative imports to work.

Comment: I added the `__init__.py` but I get the same error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. The answer of @jacinator worked for me. However, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're terribly close. I think your only problem is that you're trying to use relative imports. Inside of your `gui.py` or `vending.py` you should be able to import like this.

```py
from bar.bar import Bar
```

You shouldn't need to change anything. I duplicated your directory structure and tested this on my computer.